# Multiple three.js canvas

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas, perlin-noise

I'm working on two modified versions of this Three.js animation: https://codepen.io/farisk/pen/vrbzwL

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas1'), antialias:true, alpha: true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);

//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer.setSize(900, 900);


var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, 900/900, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 4;

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'http://nomadicschoolofthesenses.com/wp-content/themes/nomadic/images/pink6.png' );


var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 200, 200);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );


var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

var update = function() {

  // change '0.003' for more aggressive animation
  var time = performance.now() * 0.0005;
  //console.log(time)

  //go through vertices here and reposition them

  // change 'k' value for more spikes
  var k = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
      var p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
      p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.1 * noise.perlin3(p.x * k + time, p.y * k, p.z * k));
  }
  sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;


}

function animate() {
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.001;
  //sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  update();
  /* render scene and camera */
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}


window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = 900 / 900;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( 900, 900 );

}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

I need to add two different canvases (#canvas1 & #canvas2" placed in different parts of the page with different values. I duplicated the code and changed the name of variables like renderer2, etc.

```
var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas2'), antialias:true, alpha: true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer2.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);

//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer2.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer2.setSize(900, 900);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, 900/900, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 3.5;

var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/blue2.png' );

var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 200, 200);

var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
scene.add(sphere);

var update = function() {

  // change '0.003' for more aggressive animation
  var time = performance.now() * 0.0005;
  //console.log(time)

  //go through vertices here and reposition them

  // change 'k' value for more spikes
  var k = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
      var p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
      p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.1 * noise.perlin3(p.x * k + time, p.y * k, p.z * k));
  }
  sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}

function animate() {
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.001;
  //sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  update();
  /* render scene and camera */
  renderer2.render(scene,camera);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = 900 / 900;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer2.setSize( 900, 900 );

}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```

Both scripts work fine separately but if I call both of them it only renders the last one.

Comment: your codepen does not seem to work. for your problem you need to merge your `update()` `animate()` etc. functions so you only have one of each.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to what @gaitat pointed out. the solution was to merge / use the same script for all canvases and only duplicate variables as renderer, sphere, material, etc

```
var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas1'), antialias:true, alpha: true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0)

var renderer2 = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({ canvas : document.getElementById('canvas2'), antialias:true, alpha: true});
// default bg canvas color //
renderer2.setClearColor( 0xffffff, 0);

//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer.setSize(900, 900);

//  use device aspect ratio //
renderer2.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
// set size of canvas within window //
renderer2.setSize(900, 900);

var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var scene2 = new THREE.Scene();
var camera2 = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, 900/900, 0.1, 100 );
camera2.position.z = 3.5;

var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 35, 900/900, 0.1, 100 );
camera.position.z = 4;


var texture2 = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/blue2.png' );
var texture = new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'images/pink6.png' );

var sphere_geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry(200, 200, 200);

var material2 = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture2 } );
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

var sphere = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material);
var sphere2 = new THREE.Mesh(sphere_geometry, material2);
scene.add(sphere);
scene2.add(sphere2);

var update = function() {

  // change '0.003' for more aggressive animation
  var time = performance.now() * 0.0005;
  //console.log(time)

  //go through vertices here and reposition them

  // change 'k' value for more spikes
  var k = 1;
  for (var i = 0; i < sphere.geometry.vertices.length; i++) {
      var p = sphere.geometry.vertices[i];
      p.normalize().multiplyScalar(1 + 0.1 * noise.perlin3(p.x * k + time, p.y * k, p.z * k));
  }
  sphere.geometry.computeVertexNormals();
  sphere.geometry.normalsNeedUpdate = true;
sphere.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;

}

function animate() {
  sphere.rotation.y += 0.001;
  //sphere.rotation.y += 0.01;

  update();
  /* render scene and camera */
  renderer.render(scene,camera);
  renderer2.render(scene2,camera2);
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);
}

window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );

function onWindowResize(){

    camera.aspect = 900 / 900;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        camera2.aspect = 900 / 900;
    camera2.updateProjectionMatrix();

    renderer.setSize( 900, 900 );

    renderer2.setSize( 900, 900 );

}

requestAnimationFrame(animate);
```